# VB Unable to access instance of another class from one method but can from another

Tags: vb.net, instance

I have 2 main classes. The first launches the second which implements a `FIX` dll. I would like to be able to set variables/textbox.text in the first from the second. I am able to do so from te `OnCreate` method in the second, but for some reason cannot from the `OnLogon` method. Any ideas ?

Thanks

```
Imports QuickFix

Public Class GlobalVariable
    Inherits MainFIXClass

    Public Shared instance As MainFIXClass
End Class


Public Class MainFIXClass

    Private Sub CurrencyArb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GlobalVariable.instance = Me
        Connect({"D:\\Config.txt"})
    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect(args As String())
        Dim settings As New QuickFix.SessionSettings(args(0))
        Dim myApp As IApplication = New MyQuickFixApp()
        Dim storeFactory As QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory = New FileStoreFactory(settings)
        Dim logFactory As QuickFix.ILogFactory = New FileLogFactory(settings)
        Dim initiator As New QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)

        Try
            initiator.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub


End Class

Public Class MyQuickFixApp
    Inherits MainFIXClass
    Implements IApplication

    Private _session As Session = Nothing
    Private _settings As QuickFix.Session = Nothing
    Private _Store As QuickFix.IMessageStore = Nothing
    Private _instance As MainFIXClass

    Public Sub OnCreate(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnCreate
        _instance = GlobalVariable.instance
        _session = Session.LookupSession(sessionID)
        _instance.OutputTB.Text = "On Create - " & sessionID.ToString & "   " & _session.ToString              ' **************************** this line works
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnLogon(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogon
        _instance.OutputTB.Text = "Logged On"        ' **************************** this line does not work ?????
        MsgBox("Logged On")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Does the call to initiator.Start() block the Window? If so, the UI thread will be busy and hence not be able to update the TextBox. Try to put the initiator.Start() in a Thread or BackgroundWorker. Furthermore, why do all your classes inherit from MainFIXClass? Especially in the MyQuickFixApp class I don't see a sense to this.

Comment: Sorry the Inherits were from a previous workaround attempt - have stripped them out. I don't think it blocks it as at the point of creation as I am able to access textboxes etc in the window from in the OnCreate method, however it does seem blocked once I am logged on. I have added bw as a BakgroundWorker but am not sure how call the initiator.start() with the bw.RunWorkerAsync() ?

Comment: The OnCreate runs before the CurrencyArb_Load, so the Window is not yet blocked. I'll post an answer (where I can be more verbose)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the Window from blocking, you can use Threads or a BackgroundWorker. I prepared a small code snippet that demonstrates how you can use the BackgroundWorker. Please note how the DoWork and WorkCompleted methods are wired to the worker instance by using Handles.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports QuickFix
Imports QuickFix.Fields
Imports QuickFix.MessageCracker

Public Class MainFIXClass
  Implements IApplication

  Private WithEvents bw As BackgroundWorker

  Private _session As Session = Nothing
  Private _settings As QuickFix.Session = Nothing
  Private _Store As QuickFix.IMessageStore = Nothing

#Region "IApplication Methods"

  Public Sub OnCreate(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnCreate
    _session = Session.LookupSession(sessionID)
    Me.ShowOutput("On Create - " & sessionID.ToString & "   " & _session.ToString)
  End Sub

  Public Sub OnLogon(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogon
    Me.ShowOutput("Logged On")
  End Sub

#End Region

  Private Sub CurrencyArb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bw = New BackgroundWorker
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    Dim settings As New QuickFix.SessionSettings("D:\\CurrencyArb.txt")
    Dim myApp As IApplication = New MyQuickFixApp()
    Dim storeFactory As QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory = New FileStoreFactory(settings)
    Dim logFactory As QuickFix.ILogFactory = New FileLogFactory(settings)
    Dim initiator As New QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)

    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Starting initiator")
    initiator.Start()
    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Initiator started successfully")

  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_ReportProgress(source As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
    Me.ShowOutput(e.UserState.ToString())
  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_WorkCompleted(source As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
      'and exception occured
      MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    Else
      'everything was fine, you can use the result
      Dim result As Object = e.Result
    End If
    Me.ShowOutput("Worker finished")
  End Sub

  Public Sub ShowOutput(msg As String)
    Me.OutputTB.Text = msg
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - have incorporated this and it starts the initiator, it gets to the OnCreate method, but now that cannot access the Output method as I get "Cross-thread operation not valid" - used the following to call it:
_instance.ShowOutput("On Create - ")

Comment: Should I be delegating ShowOutput and using Invoke ?

Comment: Tried Delegation and Invoke - the OnCreate call to ShowOutput works now, but the one in OnLogon still doesn't

Comment: Did you try debugging the OnLogon method?

Comment: Furthermore, is initiator.Start() showing the Window or where is OutputTB defined?

Comment: The only thing in the OnLogon method is:
 _instance.ShowOutput("Logged On")
The OutPutTB is defined in the MainFIX class

Comment: If I just a MSGBOX("Logged On") in the OnLogon it does not show - I assume that as a background app it is hidden. Sorry this is all new to me and this may be a silly question, but can I not run the QuickFix app inside the MainFix class instead of as a separate class  and would this not solve my problem ?

Comment: In terms of debugging - I no longer reach a breakpoint at the first line of the OnLogon method

Comment: The problems seems to be that you don't reach the OnLogon. Maybe you put the BackgroundWorker on a wrong place. Could you post your code again?

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports QuickFix
Imports QuickFix.Fields
Imports QuickFix.MessageCracker

Public Class MainFIXClass
    Private WithEvents bw As BackgroundWorker

    Delegate Sub ShowOutputDelegate(value As String)

    Private Sub CurrencyArb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GlobalVariable.instance = Me
        bw = New BackgroundWorker
        bw.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
        Dim settings As New QuickFix.SessionSettings("D:\\CurrencyArb.txt")
        Dim myApp As IApplication = New MyQuickFixApp()
        Dim storeFactory As QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory = New FileStoreFactory(settings)
        Dim logFactory As QuickFix.ILogFactory = New FileLogFactory(settings)
        Dim initiator As New QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
        Try

            'If Not TypeOf e.Argument Is String() Then 'only take valid input
            '    Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid argument")
            'End If
            'Dim args As String() = DirectCast(e.Argument, String()) 'you can pass your arguments here

            initiator.Start()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub bw_WorkCompleted(source As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            'and exception occured
        Else
            'everything was fine, you can use the result
            Dim result As Object = e.Result
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShowOutput(msg As String)
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New ShowOutputDelegate(AddressOf ShowOutput), msg)
        Else
            Me.OutputTB.Text = msg
        End If
        Me.OutputTB.Text = msg
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class MyQuickFixApp
    Implements IApplication

    Private _session As Session = Nothing
    Private _settings As QuickFix.Session = Nothing
    Private _Store As QuickFix.IMessageStore = Nothing
    Private _instance As MainFIXClass

    Public Sub OnCreate(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnCreate
        _instance = GlobalVariable.instance
        _session = Session.LookupSession(sessionID)
        _instance.ShowOutput("On Create - " & sessionID.ToString & "   " & _session.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnLogon(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogon
        _instance.ShowOutput("Logged On")
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class GlobalVariable
    Public Shared instance As MainFIXClass
End Class
```

Comment: What about IApplication. Where is it definied? And you could potentially add everything to one class. I can provide you a snippet if you would would need one.

Comment: I think that would be the cleanest solution - if you don't mind could you add the snippet. The IApplication is implemented in the second class currently and I Dim myapp = Iapplication... in the main class

Comment: Please see my other answer, I added the snippet there. Try it out and give me feedback, if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry cannot find snippet ?

Comment: I replaced the code in my answer with the new snippet. Wait, I'll post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet when merging both classes

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports QuickFix
Imports QuickFix.Fields
Imports QuickFix.MessageCracker

Public Class MainFIXClass
  Implements IApplication

  Private WithEvents bw As BackgroundWorker

  Private _session As Session = Nothing
  Private _settings As QuickFix.Session = Nothing
  Private _Store As QuickFix.IMessageStore = Nothing

#Region "IApplication Methods"

  Public Sub OnCreate(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnCreate
    _session = Session.LookupSession(sessionID)
    Me.ShowOutput("On Create - " & sessionID.ToString & "   " & _session.ToString)
  End Sub

  Public Sub OnLogon(sessionID As SessionID) Implements IApplication.OnLogon
    Me.ShowOutput("Logged On")
  End Sub

#End Region

  Private Sub CurrencyArb_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bw = New BackgroundWorker
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()
  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork
    Dim settings As New QuickFix.SessionSettings("D:\\CurrencyArb.txt")
    Dim myApp As IApplication = New MyQuickFixApp()
    Dim storeFactory As QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory = New FileStoreFactory(settings)
    Dim logFactory As QuickFix.ILogFactory = New FileLogFactory(settings)
    Dim initiator As New QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator(myApp, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)

    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Starting initiator")
    initiator.Start()
    bw.ReportProgress(0, "Initiator started successfully")

  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_ReportProgress(source As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
    Me.ShowOutput(e.UserState.ToString())
  End Sub

  Private Sub bw_WorkCompleted(source As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
      'and exception occured
      MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    Else
      'everything was fine, you can use the result
      Dim result As Object = e.Result
    End If
    Me.ShowOutput("Worker finished")
  End Sub

  Public Sub ShowOutput(msg As String)
    Me.OutputTB.Text = msg
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How would I assign the QuickFix app to the myApp instead of pointing to the old class:
Dim myApp As IApplication = New MyQuickFixApp()

Comment: You can simply write myApp = new MainFIXClass()

Comment: Application launching fine and reaching app methods, but main app window is now hidden - have tried me.show() and me.refresh() but doesn't help. Have to head out - thanks so much for all the help.